# Extra top-level directory in "Project Files" view of newly-imported IntelliJ IDEA project

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm a new convert to IntelliJ IDEA after being an Eclipse user for more than a decade. I have a multi-module Gradle+Java project which I have attempted to import, with the structure:

```
...projects/chatty/core/
...projects/chatty/service/
...projects/chatty/web/
```

In Eclipse I would create a 'chatty' *workspace* and import the three projects separately.

What I'm *used to* (in IDEA speak) is a list of my modules at the top level, with their content directly underneath. For example:

```
Module Name
- src/main/java/
- - com.craigotis.package
```

But what I'm seeing is an extra subdirectory:

[image: Extra Subdirectory]

Which is unsightly and being on a 13" screen, shifts my class names over an extra ~30 pixels unnecessarily.

I found the 'Show Modules' option in the dropdown, but disabling it removes the **top-level** module, which leaves the rest of my modules looking a bit off:

[image: Rest of Modules]

I would have *preferred* to see the top-level module remain, while the intermediate `core (~/projects/chatty/core)` entry removed. As now, my other modules have directory paths instead of simpler names.

This is my layout in the modules area:

[image: Modules Configuration]

Is there a way to 'clean up' my project view? I'd like to see the `src/main/java` directly under the simply-named module, which is at the top-level.

I may have botched the import/project creation, I'm still translating the terminology in my head as I go.

**Edit:** The Project View isn't much better - as the `src/main/java` source directories are not flattened, and by the time I get a class opened the second half of the name is already obscured.

[image: Non-flattened Java source directories]

Comment: did you try changing view from the drop down

Comment: IntelliJ usually has one main module ("core" in your case), like a project module which can also contain source etc. and then the sub modules below it. you can try the view "Project" (default view) maybe that will suit you better.

Comment: Switch to Project view.

Comment: The "Project View" is slightly worse - even thought it lists the modules at the top level as expected, it doesn't flatten the Java directory to `src/main/java`, so once I get to my classes they're already nearly off the screen. Answer updated w/ screenshot.

Comment: I tried something, with a long directory and package name you will be better off using the "Packages" view, at least for me it takes much less space. edit: also the "Production" view shows the path as "src/main/java" as 1 tree item rather then 3.

Comment: The "Packages" view isn't really what I'm looking for, as it groups my `main` and `test` classes together under the same package. Maybe I'm getting nit-picky, but none of the configurations I've tried so far really make sense from a developer perspective: http://imgur.com/a/AneTs

Comment: Well in the "Production" view the test sources are excluded, don't know if you like that, maybe not haha. I've no idea how it looks in eclipse with such a project, maybe add a reference screenshot how you would like it to look. But seems like you have to deal with one of the views, not sure if IntelliJ plugins can add a view or if there are any better options for you. If the view is just to wide you can always scroll it to the right to hide the left side, if nothing else helps.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I'm looking for: http://www.tech-recipes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Step53.png Just a simple flattening of `src/main/java` under the name of my module. "Project Files" comes really close, but I don't know why it shows the absolute path of the directory instead of the name of the module.